# Vue.js data binding is not working what is wrong?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to show the selected item and if the selected item is undefined or null then I need to show this text. However, it's not working and shows an empty.

```
  <span>
                    {{
                      productChecked
                        ? productChecked.name
                        : 'Check the product'
                    }}
                  </span>
```

What is wrong and how can be this fixed?

Comment: please share your script and how you are defining and modifying that property

Comment: Try `{{ productChecked.name || 'Check the product' }}`

Answer (score 0):

before you use productChecked define it in date

```
data: () => ({
            productChecked:{
             name:null
             }
        }),
```